# Group By preventing Having clause from giving desired results

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is quite straight-forward but I'm having trouble populating the temp table where the number of distinct values in TypeRec is not greater than one per MatchId and RefNum fields.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (MatchId int, RefNum char(50), TypeRec char(50))  

INSERT INTO #TempTable (MatchId, RefNum, TypeRec)
SELECT   t.MatchId,
t.refNum,
t.TypeRec
FROM Transaction t (nolock) 
WHERE t.UserText = 'Proposed'    
AND t.CompanyId = 4  
AND t.RefNum = 'CreditCard'  
GROUP BY t.matchId, t.RefNum, t.TypeRec
HAVING count(distinct t.TypeRec) = 1
```

Comment: What should be the expected result? What if you pull the condition to where clause?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `typerec` from the `group by` and use `min()` or `max()`:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (MatchId, RefNum, TypeRec)
    SELECT   t.MatchId, t.refNum, min(t.TypeRec)
    FROM Transaction t (nolock) 
    WHERE t.UserText = 'Proposed'    
    AND t.CompanyId = 4  
    AND t.RefNum = 'CreditCard'  
    GROUP BY t.matchId, t.RefNum
    HAVING count(distinct t.TypeRec) = 1;
```

This counts the number of `TypeRec`s for each combination of `MatchId` and `RefNum`.  It only returns such pairs when there is one `TypeRec`.  The use `min()` is just to get that value -- the minimum of one value is that value.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is a very elegant solution.